# AngularJS - Change JSON value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to change the value of a JSON element.

I have a JSON like this in my controler

```
$scope.cfg=    {
        "cfgName" : "Name",
      "cfgs": [
        {
          "cfgsName": "form.0",
          "cfgValue": "hello"
        },
        {
          "cfgsName": "form.1",
          "cfgValue": "fname"
        },
        {
          "cfgsName": "form.2",
          "cfgValue": "how?"
        }
      ]
    };
```

Now I have a method to add one field as first element in `cfgs` array.

```
$scope.newField=function(fieldNameVal) {
    var newfield={
            "cfgValue": fieldNameVal
     };
    $scope.cfg.cfgs.splice(0,0,newfield);
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

The above is working fine. But I want to change the value of `cfgValue` of each in the array so that the value looks in order like its index.

The required json string after adding new item is

```
{
  "cfgName": "Name",
  "cfgs": [
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.0",
      "cfgValue": "someVal"
    },
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.1",
      "cfgValue": "hello"
    },
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.2",
      "cfgValue": "fname"
    },
    {
      "cfgsName": "form.3",
      "cfgValue": "how?"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following code inside `newField()` method after adding item.

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.cfg.cfgs.length;i++) {
            var val="engine.form."+i;
            $scope.cfg.cfgs[i].push({"cfgsName" : val});
        }
```

But it shows error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
```

What is the correct way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in this function:

```
$scope.newField=function(fieldNameVal) {
    var newfield = {
       cfgValue: fieldNameVal
    };
    $scope.cfg.cfgs.splice(0,0,newfield);
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

$scope.$apply is not needed. Remove it.
Second of all, it is obvious that $scope.cfg.cfgs[i] is not an array but rather an object, so to add a field to it, you would do:

```
$scope.cfg.cfgs[i].cfgsName = val;
```